# Limit number of items from a sub-category in a list of products on category page?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In my rails 4.2 application, I am showing a list of items in a page belonging to several different subcategories which belong a category. I'm also showing list items on sub category's page as well. On category's page as said, I want to show latest 5 items from each belonging subcategory, I don't to show all items belonging to one category only, which is happening with my following query.

my category model

```
has_many :products, through: :subcategories
```

my sub-category model

```
has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :category, touch: true
```

my current query

```
@products = @category.products.published.relevant(Time.zone.today).recent
                           .includes(:subcategory).limit(80)
```

How should I construct my query to limit products from a subcategory to 5, so that the page contains products from different categories?

Comment: Just for clarification, you are wanting the last 80 products under catagory, but limiting it to 5 from any single subcatagory?

Answer (score 0):

A less than elegant ruby solution

```
products_count = 0
subcatagories_count = {}
@products = []
category.
  products.published.
  relevant(Time.zone.today).
  recent.includes(:subcategory).
  find_each(batch: 80) do
    subcatagories_count[product.subcatagory_id] ||= 0
    if subcatagories_count[product.subcatagory_id] < 5
      @products << product
      products_count += 1
      subcatagories_count[product.subcatagory_id] += 1
      break if products_count >= 80
    end
end
```

- Loads in 80 at a time.
- Loops through them and adds them to @products
  if the subcatagory id Hasn't been used 5 times already
- Leaves the loop once 80 products are selected.
- Will only load once from the database if the first 80 matches.
- Will also keep searching till it finds 80 or runs out of products